# Set shipping address in PayPal Adaptive Payment call (chained and regular)

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I would like to activate the seller protection option, this requires me to send over the shipping address the buyer has filled in on my website.

I have 2 scenarios: with 1 receiver and with no receivers.

I know that I need to use the SetPaymentOptions API call but I couldn't a way to pass the PAY or PAY_PRIMARY option I have in the PAY API.

Is it possible to pass shipping address with chained payments?

Please let me know what am I missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Setup chained payment with shipping address, this can be implemented if you integrate chained payment by using embeded flow. This is the steps for you to follow to display and collect the selected shipping address

1. Call the Pay API operation with actionType set to CREATE to obtain a payment key.
2. Set senderOptions.requireShippingAddressSelection to true in your request to SetPaymentOptions and call the API operation.
3. Redirect the payment sender's browser to the embedded payment flow at https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=... after obtaining the pay key.
4. After returning from the flow, call the GetShippingAddresses API operation to obtain the selected shipping address.
   Note: This step assume that you have implemented the JavaScript for invoking the embedded payment flow, that you have set up your button or form to invoke the flow, and that you have included the code to close the window associated with the flow.

For more information, here is the reference link for you:

Adaptive payment : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Pay API : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/

SetPaymentOptions API : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/

Hope these could be helpful.

Comment: I want the user to pick his shipping address from my site.
The seller protection can only be activated using the embedded flow? this sounds a bit off....